# Calling another sites jsp page and getting response from that page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page which has a form, which on submit calls a servlet which gets some more data from the database. After fetching all the required data I need to construct a URL with all the data and call a JSP page from another site which process the data and returns a string response. I have to then parse the response and show appropriate message on the UI.

I tried to call the JSP page from data access layer using HTTPUrlConnection but I am getting `HTTP 505 error`.

```
try{ 
    URL url = new URL(mainURL+urlSB.toString()); 
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 
    String htmlText = ""; 
    String nextLine = ""; 
    while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null){ 
        htmlText = htmlText + nextLine; 
    } 
    System.out.println(htmlText);
}catch(MalformedURLException murle){ 
    System.err.println("MalformedURLException: "+ murle.getMessage()); 
}catch(IOException ioe){ 
    System.err.println("IOException: "+ ioe.getMessage()); 
}
```

Then I got the URL to servlet and used `request.getRequestDispatcher(url).include(request, response)` and I am getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/http:/xxxx:8090/test/create.jsp&quot; not found`

The other site is running that I have confirmed. I do not have access to the other site so I cannot debug it.

Can any one explain what is wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't take an URL such as `http://example.com`, but only a relative webcontent path, such as `/WEB-INF/example.jsp`.

Use [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28%29) instead:

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

This however shows the resource in its entirety. As you're using `RequestDispatcher#include()`, you seem to want to include its output (which makes however little sense in this context, but that aside). An alternative is to use `<c:import>` in your JSP. Thus, in your servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("url", url);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/your.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and in `/WEB-INF/your.jsp`:

```
<c:import url="${url}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But if I do `response.sendRedirect` then the control is passed to the new JSP page. What I want is when the processing of that JSP is done it would send me a String response which I want to capture. Using sendRedirect how can I do it?

Comment: Use `<c:import>` then. Otherwise just create another `URLConnection` on it.

Comment: using <c:import> does not work for me. Let me explain in detail. I have site x which takes input from user and pass the data to site y by creating a URL. Site y would insert the data into database and give me a id or if an error occurs in will give me error message in string like "AUTH_FAILED".